# Git over port 443

Tags: git, ssh, git-pull, git-push

I have a git repository on my server i can ssh over port 443. But now i want to pull from that server and push to it but git gives me connection refused. I think it's connecting over port 22 but i want it to connect over 443. I use tortoiseplink to connect with how can i make it connect through port 443 when pushing or pulling ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, git will execute the command in a shell where it will look for the environment variable `HOME` (which is not a Windows standard environement variable).
So make sure it does reference a correct path (any path you want)

Then ssh will look for your your public and private key in `~/.ssh/id_rsa(.pub)`.
Make sure you have them there (you can generate them in a Git bash session: `ssh-keygen -t rsa`.
Make also sure you have the public key copied in '`authorized_keys`' (which you have, since you can ssh on the server)

Finally, in your `HOME/.ssh` directory, create a file named '`config`':

```
host remoteServer
user yourLogin
hostname remoteServerName
port 443
identityfile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

You should then be able to use git pull or git push

```
git pull remoteServer:/path/to/repo.git
```

Answer (score 6):

Define your remote such that it uses port 443, or setup your ssh config so it knows to use port 443 for that host.

```
git remote add origin ssh://some.host:443/path/to/repo.git
```